# How to set a if else function with onmouseover and onmouseout event on a setInterval with images?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, onmouseover

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = ["_images/1.jpg","_images/2.jpg","_images/3.jpg",
                  "_images/4.jpg","_images/5.jpg","_images/6.jpg"];

var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm learning fundamental in `JS` how to get a changing images like a `gif`, when you `onmouseover` it, it will stop, then `onmouseout`, it resume again. I'm struggling on the below part.

```
var intervalHandler = setInterval(changeImage, 3000);

myImage.onmouseover = function(){
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
}

myImage.onmouseout = function(){
    setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you getting in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you got your example? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

To do it properly:

```
//Start initially:
var intervalHandler = setTimeout(changeImage, 3000);

myImage.onmouseover = function(){
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
}

myImage.onmouseout = function(){
    //reset the variable, so it has the new timeout.
    intervalHandler = setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
}
```

Make sure your setInterval function returns the timeout:

```
function clearInterval(timeout, period){
   return clearTimeout(callback,period);
}

function myStopFunction(timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Btw to make sure you loop indefinitely you want to execute:

```
intervalHandler = setTimeout(changeImage, 3000);
```

at the end of your changeImage function.

Comment: I trying to use if statement to execute this code. Thanks again.